# Removing axis ticks from one subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble removing axis labels from only one subplot. Everything I try removes both. My goal is to keep ticks on the left plot, but remove them on the right. Here's what I've tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

#some data.
x = np.arange(1,11)

fig = plt.figure(1)
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
grid.update(hspace=0)


plt0 = plt.subplot(grid[0,0])
plt.plot(x,x)

plt1 = plt.subplot(grid[0,1], sharey =plt0)
#The line below removes ticks from both subplots.
plt1.set_yticks([])
plt.plot(x,2*x)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `labelleft=False` to turn off the tick labels and `length=0` to hide the tick marks.

```
plt1.tick_params(labelleft=False, length=0)

plt.plot(x, 2*x)
```

[image]

Comment: setting length=0, sets the ticks on the x axis to zero as well. I still want those.